# Power supply 12vac to DC

Tags: power-supply

supposei have 12vac,after rectification my DC voltmeter measures around 15v. my question is why does 12v ac became 15v on the output?

Comment: Please improve your question, use proper punctuation. It is unclear what kind of circuit your talking about, please write a good question and provide a circuit diagram. Edit your question and try again. http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 7):

> why does 12v ac became 15v on the output?

Because of this: -

[image]

Your AC may be only 12 volts RMS but its peak value will be \$\sqrt2\$ higher at nearly 17 volts. After losing a couple of diode drops in the bridge this will become about 15.6 volts on your smoothing capacitor and, if you have a load connected there might be enough ripple voltage on the DC to give you an average DC value closer to 15 volts.

Here's some more information about the relationship between average, RMS and peak voltages on an AC waveform: -

[image]

The RMS of an AC waveform is equivalent to a DC voltage that heats a one ohm resistor the same amount so, if you wanted to prove that RMS is 0.7071x peak voltage you need to do some maths.

[image]

Comment: so that 15v is the equivalent DC voltage because i am finding transformer that will give about 30v DC. i am thinking about 24v transformer. is that ok

Comment: Probably a bad choice of words - 12 V AC will heat a 1 ohm resistor by the same amount as 12 V DC. 15 V is the peak of a sine wave that has an RMS voltage of 12 volts. I don't understand the 2nd part of your comment.

Comment: so if i have 24vac transformer ican produce a 30v DC output out of it.

Comment: 24 volts x \$\sqrt2\$ = 33.9 volts. Under load the output from a bridge rectifier will lose about 1.4 volts (typical average that may be as high as 2 volts) bringing the output to 32.5 volts. Under a bit more load and the effect of ripple can take this down to 30 volts or maybe even lower - it all depends on your output capacitor, bridge and load. I'm not going to make sweeping statements about this because there are whole books on this subject.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a one ohm resistor  and you place 1 volt DC across it.

The  current through the resistor will be one ampere, the power the resistor will dissipate will be one watt, and let's say that the resistor's temperature goes up to 100C.

Now, if you do the same thing with one volt AC you'll get exactly the same thing except that since the AC signal sometimes goes lower than one volt, in order to compensate for that and heat the resistor to the same temperature as the DC did, the AC will have to go to higher than one volt sometimes.

The value of the AC voltage required to heat the resistor to the same temperature as the DC voltage will is one volt RMS (Root Mean Square) and the peak value of the AC signal is the RMS voltage (or the DC voltage) times the square root of two.

So, if you have 12 volts RMS coming out of a transformer, that'll be about 34 volts peak-to-peak.  Then, if you full-wave rectify that signal that'll be 17 volts peak, but you'll lose about 1.5 volts across the diodes, so the best you can charge the smoothing cap up to is about 15.5 volts, give or take.

Comment: that peak voltage is what the voltmeter reading or the rms value?